# Is there a name for a java method considered as separate from any particular class?

Tags: java, oop, methods, terminology

This is a terminological question, which makes it hard to ask!

Let me give an example.  Suppose I am writing a symbolic-differentiation algorithm.  I have an abstract class Exp that is a superclass of a bunch of expression types (sums, integrals, whatever).  There is an abstract method derivative such that e.derivative() is supposed to be the derivative of the expression e.  All the concrete subclasses of Exp (imagine a whole hierarchy here) implement a derivative method that captures knowledge of how to differentiate expressions of that type.  A given method will typically compute the derivative of an expression by combining derivatives of subexpressions.

The details of the example are not important.  The important thing is that all of these scattered methods can be considered pieces of one (recursive) algorithm.  This is not true of all methods, but it's true of many of them (and the use of overloading to reuse the same method name for fundamentally different operations is considered a Bad Idea).  The question is, what is the term for 'derivative,' considered as a single function?  It's not a method; in another language it would be a function, and the various clauses (what to do with sums, what to do with integrals) would be in the same place.  I don't care which approach or languaage is better, or whether that style can be used in Java.  I just want to know what term to use for 'derivative' considered as a single function or procedure (the idea is not limited to functional programming,  nor is recursion a key feature).  When I tell someone what I did today, I'd like to say "I tried to implement a symbolic-differentation **__**, but every algorithm I thought of didn't work."  What goes in the blank?

I assume the same issue comes up for other OO languages, but Java is the one I'm most familiar with.  I'm so familiar with it that I'm pretty sure there is no standard term, but I thought I would ask our fine battery of experts here before jumping to that conclusion.

Comment: It does appear to me that "method" is the correct term. All "derivative" calls are implementations of the Exp.derivative() method and hence methods themselves.

Comment: I guess I failed to make myself clear.  First, I understand the mechanics of Java, and standard Java terminology, quite well.  A term like "subtype polymorphism" (as in pst's answer, below) won't do what I want.  I want a name for the derivative function, considered as the aggregate of all the methods that go to define it (the one in the Exp class, and those in the subclasses of Exp).  Obviously, the word "function" would work quite nicely.  The question is whether there is some other term in established usage that fills this niche.

Answer (score 2):

That sounds like "normal" [subtype polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming). The subclasses/implementations do the work but the interface is defined in a base-type. This "scatter" method is in contrast to say, the [Visitor Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) ("as good as Java gets") or Pattern Matching (not in Java) or a big manky switch/if-else controller. I'm not sure I really would call it anything else as an aggregate.

*Addendum:* you may find [Are Scala case-classes a failed experiment?](http://beust.com/weblog2/archives/000490.html) a nice read. In particular, the comments which talk about "column" vs. "row" organization and the "difference of locality" each approach has:

> > ...in OO, you divide by rows. Each row is a module, called a class. All the functions pertaining to that data variant are grouped together. This is a reasonable way of organizing things, and it's very common. The advantage is that's easy to add a data variant ... However the disadvantage is that it's hard to add new functions that vary by data type. You have to go through every class to add a new method.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for but I think I can answer this in terms of design pattern terminology. Your example sounds vaguely like the GoF [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). Here is an [example of the Strategy Pattern implemented in Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern#Java).

Comment: I like this answer as it (the Strategy Pattern) shows/allows polymorphism at work but keeps the functions "pure" in relation to the objects that contain them. If a "pattern name" is being looked for, this is likely it.

Answer (score 1):

On the contrary, I think that "method" *is* the standard term for this in the Java context.

Answer (score 0):

A *polymorphic function* can be applied to values of different types. The function may be implemented by more than one Java method.